# How to run Safe Exam Browser on Linux

Tags: linux, windows, dualboot, pop-os

for school I have to run the Safe Exam Browser (SEB), but on my Laptop I have installed Pop!_OS and SEB doesn't support Linux.

I tried running on a VM but it didn't work because the configuration is send with the exam itself and it doesnt allow the use of a VM.

Also tried running it with wine but the setup failed because it needed some .NET stuff.

I have two options:

1. make a LiveOS with SEB intsalled (I tried but I coudnt make a ISO that works)
2. Dual Boot

If there is no other option than dual boot has somebody a good tutorial with which I can keep my data?

Comment: You might try getting wine directly from its repositories, https://www.tecmint.com/install-wine-on-ubuntu-and-linux-mint/,  and installing Mono, https://wiki.winehq.org/Mono, which does .net . Not sure of that works on Pop!OS, but easily done in Ubuntu, Mint, etc. Otherwise, contact the institution for help.

Comment: Nope. Use Windows and that means installed, of course. There's no "live" Windows.

Comment: @ChanganAuto There is Windows LiveOS where you can boot from a stick. Its called WindowsPE

Comment: @elite_tnt - No; It's actually called Windows to Go and support for it was discontinued over 5 years ago.  It also absolutely is NOT WinPE.  **WinPE does NOT have the ability to do what you want.** WinPE is something else entirely.

Answer (score 0):

I have unfortunately found no answer. But here is how I solve the problem of using SEB:

Remote Connection to my PC at home with Windows 10 and SEB installed were I do the tests.

EDIT:

For the remote connection I used WireGuard on my Laptop, activated RemteDesktop on my PC, installed Remmina as RDP Client and so I can start the PC I used WakeOnLAN.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).